# Converting phone to SIP gateway

Tags: sip

Is there a way to use my phone as a SIP GSM gateway, so I can make and receive cellular calls using a SIP phone and/or re-route them through a SIP PBX?

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/best-sip-application

Comment: @Al Everett: The question you linked is about turning your phone into a SIP softphone. I am trying to figure out how to serve SIP, not for another client.

Comment: Which is why I wrote "possibly".

Comment: @Al Everett: Understood. Yet it would be nice SIPdroid to support that!

Comment: asterisk+bluetooth dongle on server, and chan_celliax or chan_mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible until we have source code of mobile device drivers responsible for radio communication, You can read a related article which describe that [Why it is not possible to use phone as sip to gsm gateway](http://www.ictinnovations.com/using-android-phone-as-gsm-gateway).

according that article

> Third hurdle to make Android work as a GSM Gateway is that vendor RIL
>   is not open source. Every vendor has their own library of RIL that
>   communicates with Radio Daemon (rild).

Answer (score 1):

No.

At the moment, that is not available. Potentially you could port a linux application for this to your Android phone, easier if it's a CLI application, but as it stands at the moment there is no application that can do what you ask.

Comment: Leaving question open, because if I ask it again in the future, when an application like this exists, it might be considered as duplicate to this and get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to require device in which the in-call audio can be sourced/obtained by an application.  On the typical android phone architecture, in call audio is handled by the radio co-processor, entirely out of reach of anything running under linux/android - the same reason why you can't really record calls.

If you got a rooted phone with (or hackable for) USB host support and found a usb audio dongle with linux drivers you could theoretically loop around and plug that into the phone's headset jack... but wouldn't it be simpler just to buy SIP gateway service from someone?

Comment: And in the case of Samsung where the radio processor is simply the dsp?