# Android phone as a GSM gateway

Tags: voip

I am currently in a foreign country. Is there anyway which I can make calls using my home country Android device from here? I mean I connect to that phone through VoIP and Android device set up a call through GSM network.

Comment: If your phone and a PC were connected to home Wi-Fi, you could probably remote into that PC and do it via the solution here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/66533/1465

Comment: Something like this: [Converting phone to SIP gateway](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2692/16575)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this very well written document](http://www.ictinnovations.com/using-android-phone-as-gsm-gateway), this is NOT possible.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.